# Can you expand #define's into string literals?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to get the C++ pre-processor to expand a #define'ed value into a string literal?
for example:

```
#define NEW_LINE '\n'
Printf("OutputNEW_LINE"); //or whatever
```

This looks to me like it should be possible as it's before compilation?
Or is there a better design pattern to achieve this kind of behaviour (without resorting to runtime fixes like sprintf)?

**EDIT** I understand that #define's can be evil, but for arguments sake...

**ADDITIONAL** Does anyone have any criticism of this approach?

Comment: @GMan any 'less ugly' alternatives?

Comment: Well, you can just use \n directly in Strings. The C standard mandates that this single character will be expanded to whatever the platform uses as line delimiter/terminator, at least when writing to text files and the console.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This will do it:

```
#define NEW_LINE "\n"         // Note double quotes
Printf("Output" NEW_LINE);
```

(Technically it's the compiler joining the strings rather than the preprocessor, but the end result is the same.)

Answer (score 6):

If I remember correctly it is

```
Printf("Output" NEW_LINE);
```

Comment: So this will be expanded at build time not via Printf's formating facility?

Comment: Yes, the C compiler will automatically concatenate adjacent string literals, although the #define should define NEW_LINE as "\n" and not '\n' for that to work, I think.

Comment: +1 to counteract the unwarranted downvote. (It wasn't my downvote, but perhaps it was because the code won't work with #define NEW_LINE '\n' (with single quotes) as given in Adam's question. Harsh but a possibility.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following.

```
#define NEW_LINE "\n"
printf("Output" NEW_LINE);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#define NEW_LINE "\n"
printf("Output" NEW_LINE); //or whatever
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Well....

```
printf("Output%s", NEW_LINE);
```

Comment: exactly, but much easier to maintain in the long term :)

Comment: mmmm... Not really, you'd still have to recompile everything if the #define changes and the missing comma should be no cause of trouble if something in the text changes, as you can still add placeholders and variables without breaking something. At least in my opinion.